# Translating R code about treatment into Effect size. Expected mean and variance

Tags: r, variance, expected-value, effect-size, moments

Using R, I created groups of individuals with trait values. Then I simulated a treatment that modified their trait value (see below). Finally I run a one-way Anova on them using the individuals traits value as dependent variable and the groups as independent variable. I want to know how does my **treatment magnitude can be translated into Effect Size** in order to compare my results with what I would expect using the pwr package. I don't want to measure the effect size afterward, I want to know what effect size did I simulated. I'm not sure of which words I should use, I might have better to call it the expected effect size given the treatment I simulated.

Here is the definition of effect size for Anova as defined by Cohen.

```
Effect.size = sqrt(Epsilon.over.all.i(p.i *(mu.i - mu)^2)/sigma.square)
    mu.i = the mean of the group i
    mu = the mean of the overall
    p.i = n.i / N
    n.i = the number of individuals in group i
    N = the total number of individuals
    sigma square = the error variance within groups
```

You'll find it more explicitly written directly on my [source](http://www.statmethods.net/stats/power.html) (one third of the page in the ANOVA section)

Here is my R script:

```
# Create individuals and groups.    
N=100 # sample size
nb.groups = 4
sd=1
My.data = data.frame(
group=rep(1:nb.groups,n/nb.groups),
Trait=rnorm(n=N, mean=0,sd=sd)
)

# Simulate a treatment

Treatment = 0.55
```

Way 1 of simulating a treatment

```
# Adding a fixed value if Treatment = 4, nb.groups=4:
  # group 1: nothing is added
  # group 2: 1/3 * 4 is added
  # group 3: 2/3 * 4 is added
  # group 4: 3/3 * 4 is added

for (i in 2:nb.groups){
     My.data[which(My.mat[,1]==i),2] = 
     My.data[which(My.mat[,1]==i),2] + Treatment*((i-1)/(nb.groups-1))
}
```

Way 2 of simulating a treatment

```
# Adding a value drawn from a random distribution which mean equals the fixed value we added in Way 1 and sd always equals my parameter "sd"

for (i in 1:nb.groups){
     My.data[which(My.mat[,1]==i),2] =
     My.data[which(My.mat[,1]==i),2] + rnorm(N/nb.groups,mean=Treatment*((i-1)/(nb.groups-1)),sd=sd)
}
```

I repeat my question: Both for way 1 and way 2, I'm trying to find a function that "translate" the parameter "Treatment" into the common "Effect size".

In order to use the above formula for effect-size, I must be able to infer the expected mu.i, mu and sigma.square but I don't know how to do that !

Here is the ANOVA I ran:

```
aov(my.data$Trait~my.data$group)
```

P.s. I already posted this question but did not get any answer or comment. So I try again. Please let me know if my question is unanswerable.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really understand what the dependent variables and the independent variables are in your data. Is `treatment` the dependent variable? Also, have you considered using linear regression, together with $partial R^2$ to measure effect size?

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert for your comment. I updated my post (first paragraph) hoping my problem gets more clear. Treatment is a fixed number, according to this fixed number the trait values of individuals in group 2 will increase a bit, those of group 3 will increase a bit more etc... I ran this anova inds.trait.values~groups and . I want to know what is my effect size (or should I say expected effect size ?!) given my treatment value and the way I implemented this value to modify trait values.

Comment: @Remi.b I think some of the confusion results from the way you use the term “effect size”. It is more a concept (the strength of the effect, e.g. of one variable on another) than a single value. Consequently, there are several effect size measures and it's not clear what “computing *the* effect size” would mean. Even the raw difference in means between two conditions is a perfectly reasonable (unstandardized) effect size measure. If I understood you correctly, you are specifically interested in Cohen's $f$ to carry out a power analysis? Is that right?

Comment: Yes, I'm interested in the Cohen's f to carry out a power analysis. Through my simulations I calculated the sensitivity/power in relation to the value of "Treatment". I want to compare the results I get through my simulations with the predictions given by Cohen's work. Thanks again for your help Gaël.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already defined $\mu_i$, $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ in your simulation:

- The $\mu_i$ are the group means, so in your example $\mu_1 = 0$, $\mu_2 = 1/3 * \text{Treatment} = .18$, etc.
- Since the design is balanced, the grand mean is the average of all group means or, in your case, $\mu = Treatment * 6/3 = Treatment/2 = .275$
- $\sigma^2$ is the square of the standard deviation in the `rnorm` statement so that $\sigma^2 = 1$ in your case.

Comment: In way 2, isn't my sigma.square higher in the second way of computing the mean ? My question now is actually is the expected sd(rnorm(n,mean.1,sd.1) + rnorm(n,mean.2,sd.1)) == sd.1 ?

Comment: This is the sum of two normally distributed random variables. Since they are uncorrelated (by construction), the variance of the sum is the sum of the variances (the relationship does not hold for the SD, you have to work with the variances).

Comment: So, in my example var(rnorm(n,mean.1,sd.1)+rnorm(n,mean.2,sd.1))==sd.1^2+sd.1^2. In other words the sigma square of the Cohen's f should be 2 (and not 1) as the two sd equal 1 (in my original question). Is it correct ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.